# is it mandatory to have some key field in hbm

Tags: java, hibernate, temp-tables

i am using hibernate as ORM tool, i am facing one problem,

i need to map a Global Temporary table to HBM. Now, the problem is with key, i know that in the hbm it is madatory to have some key fields, but what should i put, as any column can be null at any point of time, and table may have multiple records and the column value can be same for all.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just introduce a surrogate key for this very purpose. An incremental number field should suffice.

Comment: @ Adeel: i know, that i can some incremental value, but with that i also need to define some end value, as it a global temporary table, so it can contain millions of records... and for that if i use incremental value then , it is not a good option i feel..

Comment: @Mrityunjay: I mean just use a sequence or something, or may be UUID. But I think a sequence will suffice.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, then you can make use of `ROWID`, but never try to insert or update one. This is the column which is maintained by oracle for its own use.

Comment: @Mrityunjay: I made my suggestions after reading your comment on Derek's post. Please read my suggestions carefully and give it a try.

Comment: @Adeel  : but the problem is that i cannot add any more column in it, i have to reuse the existing table only.

Comment: @Mrityunjay: Are you using Oracle? If yes, you already have a column `ROWID` in every table. You can make use of that. Try to read my few last comments carefully.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be design problems with your DB. But to deal with your question, I would recommend that you add an id field that can be populated with a automatically generated unique id. Then it doesn't matter that the rest of your fields are blank.

Comment: @ Derek : i know, that i can add an UUID, or some automatically generated id, but that i have kept as my last option.. Apart from that is there any way..

Comment: I would think it was possible to have a row with every field blank. I've never done it. Any time I've encountered DB designs which start to head this direction, I've rethought and redesigned the database. Another option worth considering is to ask why you would need to have every field optional? Depending on the design of the software and the data lifecycles, I'd be asking if it's writing to the database too soon and perhaps should wait until more solid data has been assembled. In other words - can you do this in memory rather than a db?